# Audio output being trown back to audio input

Tags: audio, headphones

All my audio output seems to be routed right back into my audio input channel so when I'm on online meets (that is not dependant on chrome since I've got this also on installed apps) everyone can hear the same thing I'm hearing.

I'm using a 13-inch, 2017, MacBook Pro and this seems to happen independently of using or not a headphone.

What can I do to fix this issue? I've searched online and found nothing for this on Mac, only a few mentions for people on windows.

Comment: Do you have any third party sound apps (eg. Soundflower) installed?  Boot into Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting) and see if the problem  continues.  If it doesn’t, there’s a 3rd party app/kext being loaded that’s causes the problem.

Comment: Could you go into "sound" under system preferences and take a screenshot of both the "output" and "input" sections? You may have selected the wrong sound output/input, but it is hard to know.

Comment: No third party apps installed that mess with audio. Will try booting into safemode to see if it works. https://imgur.com/a/DmvuvNY My input/output is clean, 23MP55 is my monitor that does not have an audio output.

I tried everything I could possibily think of but nothing works.